# VerifyStatic on System class is failing with PowerMock 2.0.2

Tags: mockito, junit4, powermock, mockstatic

Reference to verifystatic on System class is failing after upgrading powermock version to 2X from 1X

Below are my current configurations
mockito-core - 2.27.0
powermock-api-mockito2 - 2.0.2
powermock-api-support - 2.0.2
powermock-module-junit4 - 2.0.2

Below code is working fine with powermock 1X

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ System.class })
public class SystemMockStaticTest {
  @Test
  public void testSystem() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
    System.getProperties();
  }
}
```

I have made below changes to make it work with powermock2.0.2

```
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(System.class);
    System.getProperties();
```

On running the test getting below exception.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.System
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class
    at SystemMockStaticTest.testSystem(SystemMockStaticTest.java:19)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Please help on finding a fix for this exception.